# Python indexing and applying a boolean mask to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary in which I index like the following:

```
data[0][0]
data[0][1]
data[0][2]
...
```

The arrays in each dictionary element are a 2D [x,y].

I also have a 2D array of 1's and 0's that I would like to use a mask to each index above. To do this, I have to do something like:

```
tmp0 = data[0][0]
tmp0[boolean_array.astype(bool)] = -999

tmp1 = data[0][1]
tmp1[boolean_array.astype(bool)] = -999

...
...
```

Is there a way do apply the mask to all of the indexes at once while also keeping the dictionary intact (i.e., not creating a new variable for every dictionary index)?